# How to add a slider input field to PDF forms

Tags: pdf

I am trying to create a PDF form which contains a slider input. Currently Adobe acrobat doesn't support slider inputs. Is there any hackish way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to some extent. You can read out the mouse coordinates within a button field (actually, any field, but for our purpose, it is a button field). If you do that in the MouseUp event, you then can move the icon of the button field to that position, and of course also use those coordinates for your other actions.

This gives the effect of clicking in a slider and on release have the according value. What you won't get is continuous moving of the slider (which would be the icon), or rapid update of the numeric position of the mouse. The latter could be done with a setInterval() loop with a short interval time.

I have implemented such "sliders" in several projects in the past, and it works reasonably well.

Note that this works only with PDF viewers understanding Acrobat JavaScript.